# Search in PDF, index it?

Tags: php, python, pdf

I have 1000+ PDF searchables.

I need some plugin or aplication to index it, such as  (http) joomla.natemaxfield.com

Answer (score 2):

We use Swish-e to index our website which includes thousands of PDF's, Word files and even WordPerfect files.  It works great.  It is free, open source and integrates well with PHP.

http://swish-e.org/index.html

From their homepage:

> Swish-e is a fast, flexible, and free
>   open source system for indexing
>   collections of Web pages or other
>   files. Swish-e is ideally suited for
>   collections of a million documents or
>   smaller. Using the GNOME™ libxml2
>   parser and a collection of filters,
>   Swish-e can index plain text, e-mail,
>   PDF, HTML, XML, Microsoft®
>   Word/PowerPoint/Excel and just about
>   any file that can be converted to XML
>   or HTML text. Swish-e is also often
>   used to supplement databases like the
>   MySQL® DBMS for very fast full-text
>   searching.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html). It can do what you want quite easily. Also, please search for similar questions as this is a possible dupe of: [Python module for converting PDF to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text)