# How do I use pdfminer as a library

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I am trying to get text data from a pdf using [pdfminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html).  I am able to extract this data to a .txt file successfully with the pdfminer command line tool pdf2txt.py.  I currently do this and then use a python script to clean up the .txt file.  I would like to incorporate the pdf extract process into the script and save myself a step.

[I thought I was on to something when I found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text), but I didn't have success with any of the solutions.  Perhaps the function listed there needs to be updated again because I am using a newer version of pdfminer.

[I also tried the function shown here, but it also did not work.](http://www.herblainchbury.com/2010/05/opendatabc-extracting-data-from-a4ca.html)

Another approach I tried was to call the script within a script using `os.system`.  This was also unsuccessful.

I am using Python version 2.7.1 and pdfminer version 20110227.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html#basic)?

Comment: I did look over the api thank you, but unfortunately my python skills are not strong enough to get a working function.

Comment: You may find this solution to a similar question useful: stackoverflow.com/a/61857301/7483211

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting text from a PDF file using PDFMiner in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version I finally produced that worked for me. The following just simply returns the string in a PDF, given its filename. I hope this saves someone time.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf(path):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp)
    fp.close()
    device.close()

    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str
```

This solution was valid until [API changes in November 2013](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/#api-changes).

Comment: Just FYI, this no longer works on the current version of pdfminer - I get "ImportError: cannot import name process_pdf"

Comment: over here is a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494211/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-pdfminer-in-python (as of mid november '15)

Comment: process_pdf was merely replaced by PDFPageInterpreter

Comment: StringIO is also gone and you can use "from io import StringIO" instead

Answer (score 80):

Here is a new solution that works with the latest version:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str
```

Comment: great! finally a running solution without using `process_pdf` :) I tried that with the `simple1.pdf` from the [official git repository](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/blob/master/samples/simple1.pdf)

Comment: This is working for version `pdfminer 20131113`. Thanks.

Comment: @czw. How do you use this with the built in options? Is there a way to specify which page number to convert?

Comment: if you want to get a html output just add HTMLConverter to imports and in the function, instead of TextConverter put HTMLConverter. Simple as that.

Comment: You rock man it is also working with pdfminer latest version(20140328):



import pdfminer
print pdfminer.__version__
20140328

Comment: Great with one minor edit: DON'T use str as a variable name. str is a python function.

Comment: I get `ImportError: No module named pdfpage`

Comment: Where does `file` come from? Did you mean `open`?

Answer (score 13):

I know it is poor taste to answer your own question, but I think I may have figured this out and I don't want anyone else to waste their time looking for a solution to my problem.

I followed the suggestion in a one of the links posted in my question and re-purposed the current pdf2txt.py script included with pdfminer. Here is the function in case it is useful to anyone else.  Thanks to the user skyl for posting that answer, all I had to to was make a couple of changes to make it work with the current version of pdfminer.

This function take a pdf and creates a .txt file in the same directory with the same name.

```
def convert_pdf(path, outtype='txt', opts={}):
import sys
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFDocument, PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter, process_pdf
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice, TagExtractor
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.cmapdb import CMapDB
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
import getopt

outfile = path[:-3] + outtype
outdir = '/'.join(path.split('/')[:-1])

# debug option
debug = 0
# input option
password = ''
pagenos = set()
maxpages = 0
# output option
# ?outfile = None
# ?outtype = None
outdir = None
#layoutmode = 'normal'
codec = 'utf-8'
pageno = 1
scale = 1
showpageno = True
laparams = LAParams()
for (k, v) in opts:
    if k == '-d': debug += 1
    elif k == '-p': pagenos.update( int(x)-1 for x in v.split(',') )
    elif k == '-m': maxpages = int(v)
    elif k == '-P': password = v
    elif k == '-o': outfile = v
    elif k == '-n': laparams = None
    elif k == '-A': laparams.all_texts = True
    elif k == '-V': laparams.detect_vertical = True
    elif k == '-M': laparams.char_margin = float(v)
    elif k == '-L': laparams.line_margin = float(v)
    elif k == '-W': laparams.word_margin = float(v)
    elif k == '-F': laparams.boxes_flow = float(v)
    elif k == '-Y': layoutmode = v
    elif k == '-O': outdir = v
    elif k == '-t': outtype = v
    elif k == '-c': codec = v
    elif k == '-s': scale = float(v)
#
#PDFDocument.debug = debug
#PDFParser.debug = debug
CMapDB.debug = debug
PDFResourceManager.debug = debug
PDFPageInterpreter.debug = debug
PDFDevice.debug = debug
#
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

outtype = 'text'

if outfile:
    outfp = file(outfile, 'w')
else:
    outfp = sys.stdout
device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)


fp = file(path, 'rb')
process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,
                check_extractable=True)
fp.close()
device.close()
outfp.close()
return
```

Comment: it is okay to answer your own questions, don't worry.

Comment: I also repurposed that code. It just could be somewhat slimmer

Comment: It's quite desirable to answer your own question, because of the reason you mentioned

Answer (score 13):

Here's my solution

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO
import os 

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path, pages=None):
    if not pages:
        pagenums = set()
    else:
        pagenums = set(pages)
    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)

    infile = open(path, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    return text
```

For example you just want to read the first 3 pages of a pdf file:

```
text = convert_pdf_to_txt('../Data/EN-FINAL Table 9.pdf', pages=[0,1,2])
```

pdfminer.six==20160614

python: 3.x

Comment: Nice! This worked for me.

Python 3.6.2
pdfminer.six

Comment: Best solution under Python 3.6 / pdfminer.six / Windows 7

Comment: Hi. this returns string like this for my pdf. '(cid:42)(cid:82)(cid:89)(cid:72)(cid:85)(cid:81)(cid:80)(cid:72)(cid:81)(cid:87)(cid:3)(cid:57)(cid:72)(cid:75)(cid:76)(cid:70)(cid:79)(cid:72)(cid:86)\n\n(cid:20)(cid:25)(cid:18)(cid:19)(cid:2id:87)(cid:86)(cid:15)(cid:3)(cid:37)(cid:79)'

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me using the most recent version of pdfminer (as of September 2014):

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
import unicodedata, codecs
from io import StringIO

def getPDFText(pdfFilenamePath):
    retstr = StringIO()
    parser = PDFParser(open(pdfFilenamePath,'r'))
    try:
        document = PDFDocument(parser)
    except Exception as e:
        print(pdfFilenamePath,'is not a readable pdf')
        return ''
    if document.is_extractable:
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr,retstr, codec='ascii' , laparams = LAParams())
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
        return retstr.getvalue()
    else:
        print(pdfFilenamePath,"Warning: could not extract text from pdf file.")
        return ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = getPDFText(path)
```

Comment: what to do when it says the pdf is not readable?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an answer that works with `pdfminer.six` running python 3.6. It uses the `pdfminer.high_level` module that abstracts away a lot of the underlying detail if you just want to get out the raw text from a simple PDF file.

```
import pdfminer
import io

def extract_raw_text(pdf_filename):
    output = io.StringIO()
    laparams = pdfminer.layout.LAParams() # Using the defaults seems to work fine

    with open(pdf_filename, "rb") as pdffile:
        pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(pdffile, output, laparams=laparams)

    return output.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 4):

The following modification of the non-process_pdf answers pulls the text straight from a URL string name and works with version 20140328 and Python 2.7:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
def convert_pdf_to_txt(url):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    scrape = urlopen(url).read()
    fp = StringIO(scrape)

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    textstr = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return textstr
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with scraped data via urllib2, try this (which is developed and explained [here](http://www.herblainchbury.com/2010/05/opendatabc-extracting-data-from-a4ca.html)):

```
def pdf_to_text(scraped_pdf_data): 
    from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf 
    from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice 
    from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter 
    from pdfminer.layout import LAParams 

    import StringIO 
    fp = StringIO.StringIO() 
    fp.write(scraped_pdf_data) 
    fp.seek(0) 
    outfp = StringIO.StringIO() 

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager() 
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, laparams=LAParams()) 
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp) 
    device.close() 

    t = outfp.getvalue() 
    outfp.close() 
    fp.close() 
    return t
```

Like the other answers, the code here adapts the pdf2txt utility that PDFMiner itself provides. You can thus also convert to html or xml -- just sub `HTMLConverter` or `XMLConverter` for `TextConverter` everywhere above.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works for me with latest version of PDFMiner it takes path of pdf and return text in .txt format.

P.S: This is a modification of above answer.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path, outtype='txt'):
    outfile = path[:-3] + outtype
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    if outfile:
        outfp = file(outfile, 'w')
    else:
        outfp = sys.stdout
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    outfp.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 3):

just in case anyone still needs this,
got it working with requests and python 3.4.
thanks to @bahmait for his answer above :)

```
import requests

from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams


def pdf_to_text(url=None):
    text = None
    pdf = requests.get(url)

    if pdf.ok:
        fp = StringIO(str(pdf.content, 'utf-8'))
        outfp = StringIO()

        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, laparams=LAParams())
        process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp)
        device.close()

        text = outfp.getvalue()
        outfp.close()
        fp.close()
    return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world_text = pdf_to_text("https://bytebucket.org/hsoft/pdfminer3k/raw/28edfc91caed830674ca0b928f42571f7dee6091/samples/simple1.pdf")
    no_pdf = pdf_to_text('http://www.google.com/404')
    print(hello_world_text)
    print(no_pdf)
```

Comment: have you given this guy a try? [link]https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k ... doesnt look like its really supported anymore, but it gave me a good jump off point. in the end, i used their pdf2txt module mixed a few methods from pypdf2 for my specific use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cleaned up version I finally produced that worked for me. The following just simply returns the string in a PDF, given its filename. I hope this saves someone time.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf(path):

    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp)
    fp.close()
    device.close()

    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str
```

can anybody say me : is there any specific place where the pdf file  is to be placed??

Answer (score 1):

Only if someone still needs it: How to print the HTML from a PDF using PDFMiner:

```
import sys
import getopt
from Core.Interfaces.IReader import IReader
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFDocument, PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter, process_pdf
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice, TagExtractor
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.cmapdb import CMapDB
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from cStringIO import StringIO

class PdfReader(object):
def __init__(self):
    pass

def readText(self,path, outtype='text', opts={}):
    outfile = path[:-3] + outtype
    outdir = '/'.join(path.split('/')[:-1])
    # debug option
    debug = 0
    # input option
    password = ''
    pagenos = set()
    maxpages = 0
    # output option
    # ?outfile = None
    # ?outtype = None
    outdir = None
    #layoutmode = 'normal'
    codec = 'utf-8'
    pageno = 1
    scale = 1
    showpageno = True
    laparams = LAParams()
    for (k, v) in opts:
        if k == '-d': debug += 1
        elif k == '-p': pagenos.update( int(x)-1 for x in v.split(',') )
        elif k == '-m': maxpages = int(v)
        elif k == '-P': password = v
        elif k == '-o': outfile = v
        elif k == '-n': laparams = None
        elif k == '-A': laparams.all_texts = True
        elif k == '-V': laparams.detect_vertical = True
        elif k == '-M': laparams.char_margin = float(v)
        elif k == '-L': laparams.line_margin = float(v)
        elif k == '-W': laparams.word_margin = float(v)
        elif k == '-F': laparams.boxes_flow = float(v)
        elif k == '-Y': layoutmode = v
        elif k == '-O': outdir = v
        elif k == '-t': outtype = v
        elif k == '-c': codec = v
        elif k == '-s': scale = float(v)

    print laparams
    #
    #PDFDocument.debug = debug
    #PDFParser.debug = debug
    CMapDB.debug = debug
    PDFResourceManager.debug = debug
    PDFPageInterpreter.debug = debug
    PDFDevice.debug = debug
    #
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()

    #outtype = 'text'

    outfp = StringIO()

    device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)


    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    process_pdf(rsrcmgr, device, fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,
                    check_extractable=True)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    print outfp.getvalue()
    outfp.close()

    return



reader = PdfReader()
opt = map(None,['-W','-L','-t'],[0.5,0.4,'html'])
reader.readText("/test_data/test.pdf","html",opt)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me in python 3.
It requires the PDFMiner.six package

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

The code is as follows (same code as everyone, with minor fixes):

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from six import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()

    return str.replace("\\n","\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, I am one of the maintainers of [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six). It is a community-maintained version of pdfminer for python 3.

Nowadays, it has multiple api's to extract text from a PDF, depending on your needs. Behind the scenes, all of these api's use the same logic for parsing and analyzing the layout.

(All the examples assume your PDF file is called *example.pdf*)

**Commandline**

If you want to extract text just once you can use the commandline tool pdf2txt.py:

```sh
$ pdf2txt.py example.pdf
```

**High-level api**

If you want to extract text (properties) with Python, you can use the high-level api. This approach is the go-to solution if you want to programmatically extract information from a PDF.

```py
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text

# Extract text from a pdf.
text = extract_text('example.pdf')

# Extract iterable of LTPage objects.
pages = extract_pages('example.pdf')
```

**Composable api**

There is also a composable api that gives a lot of flexibility in handling the resulting objects. For example, it allows you to create your own layout algorithm. This method is suggested in the other answers, but I would only recommend this when you need to customize some component.

```
from io import StringIO

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser

output_string = StringIO()
with open('example.pdf', 'rb') as in_file:
    parser = PDFParser(in_file)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

print(output_string.getvalue())
```

Comment: Hi @Pieter, could you please look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614884/pdfminer-get-font-size-from-headers-per-each-page-iteration

Answer (score -1):

The following code snippets is able to extract plain text from pdf documents using the latest version of pdfminer(as of 23-Mar-2016). Hope this helps.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    fp = file(path, 'rb')

    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    parser.set_document(doc)

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages,        password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    print text
    return text

convert_pdf_to_txt(<path_of_the_pdf_file>)
```