# Whitespace gone from PDF extraction, and strange word interpretation

Tags: python, pdf, unicode, pypdf

Using the snippet below, I've attempted to extract the text data from [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6160029/Aggarwal%20et%20al.%20-%202008%20-%20Asynchronous%20decoding%20of%20dexterous%20finger%20movements%20using%20M1%20neurons.pdf) PDF file.

```
import pyPdf

def get_text(path):
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    content = ""
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"  # Extract text from page and add to content
    # Collapse whitespace
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content
```

The [output I obtain](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1047657/), however,is devoid of whitespace between most of the words. This makes it difficult to perform natural language processing on the text (my ultimate goal, here).

Also, the 'fi' in the word 'finger' is consistently interpreted as something else. This is rather problematic since this paper is about spontaneous finger movements...

Does anybody know why this might be happening? I don't even know where to start!

Comment: 'fi' is a [typographic ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), which answers one part of your question.

Comment: The PDF is gone. Can you re-upload it somewhere where it stays, e.g. https://github.com/py-pdf/sample-files/ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your PDF file doesn't have printable space characters, it simply positions the words where they need to go.  You'll have to do extra work to figure out the spaces, perhaps by assuming multi-character runs are words, and put spaces between them.

If you can select text in the PDF reader, and have spaces appear properly, then at least you know there is enough information to reconstruct the text.

"fi" is a typographic ligature, shown as a single character.  You may find this is also happening with "fl", "ffi", and "ffl".  You can use string replacement to substitute "fi" for the fi ligature.

Comment: Exactly. The spaces and "fi" were lost in the translation from text to PDF and they're not coming back.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, Thanks for your reply!  Could you clarify what you mean by "assuming multi-character runs are words"? Second, given that 'fi' is a typographic ligature how can I go about recognizing such special characters a PDF and translating them into two (or more) separate characters?  In other words, can you suggest a method for automatically handling such cases?

Comment: @biz yes this question needs to be answered. I'm getting into the same kind of problem myself

Answer (score 17):

Without using the PyPdf2 use Pdfminer library package which has same functionality, as bellow. I got the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725278/how-do-i-use-pdfminer-as-a-library) and as i wanted I edited it, this code gives me a text file which has white-space among words. I work with anaconda and python 3.6. for install PdfMiner for python 3.6 you can use this [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pdfminer.six).

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO

class PdfConverter:

   def __init__(self, file_path):
       self.file_path = file_path
# convert pdf file to a string which has space among words 
   def convert_pdf_to_txt(self):
       rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
       retstr = StringIO()
       codec = 'utf-8'  # 'utf16','utf-8'
       laparams = LAParams()
       device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
       fp = open(self.file_path, 'rb')
       interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
       password = ""
       maxpages = 0
       caching = True
       pagenos = set()
       for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
           interpreter.process_page(page)
       fp.close()
       device.close()
       str = retstr.getvalue()
       retstr.close()
       return str
# convert pdf file text to string and save as a text_pdf.txt file
   def save_convert_pdf_to_txt(self):
       content = self.convert_pdf_to_txt()
       txt_pdf = open('text_pdf.txt', 'wb')
       txt_pdf.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
       txt_pdf.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pdfConverter = PdfConverter(file_path='sample.pdf')
    print(pdfConverter.convert_pdf_to_txt())
```

Answer (score 13):

### New Answer: pypdf

PyPDF2 was [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/), all of its features were moved back into [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) and pypdf improved A LOT. **Use pypdf**:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader  # pip install pypdf --upgrade

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
for page in reader.pages:
    print(page.extract_text())
```

You can also use `page.extract_text(extraction_mode="layout")` ([docs](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extract-text.html))

I also wrote a [benchmark for text extraction](https://github.com/py-pdf/benchmarks) that shows that pypdf has top-quality text-extraction.

### Old Answer: pdftotext

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Use pdftotext to extract text from PDFs."""

import pdftotext

with open("foobar.pdf") as f:
    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

# Iterate over all the pages
for page in pdf:
    print(page)
```

Comment: This should be the top voted answer in my opinion. I also wish it was the first entry when doing an online search.

Comment: @BFurtado make sure dependencies are installed 
`sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install build-essential libpoppler-cpp-dev pkg-config python-dev`

Comment: @Martin Thoma is there any other parameter in pdftotext.PDF(f,..) because it's preserve the horinzontal white space but not vertical line space

Answer (score 4):

PyPDF doesnt read newline charecter.

So use PyPDF4

Install it using

```
pip install PyPDF4
```

and use this code as an example

```
import PyPDF4
import re
import io

pdfFileObj = open(r'3134.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(1)
pages_text = pageObj.extractText()

for line in pages_text.split('\n'):
    #if re.match(r"^PDF", line):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Note : as for today, PyPDF4 has not been updated since 2018 and the homepage is down...

Comment: Use pypdf: https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/ . Since this answer was written in 2019 it does not consider the 2022 and following updates of pypdf.

Answer (score 1):

I tried given answers here but it did not work for me. the following works in my case:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import pytesseract

images = convert_from_path("sample.pdf")
for i,image in enumerate(images,start=1):
    image.save(f"./images/page_{i}.jpg","JPEG")

print(pytesseract.image_to_string("./images/page_1.jpg"))
```

The idea here is to first convert the PDF to an image and then read the text from it. This approach preserves the whitespace.

Dependecies:

- conda install -c conda-forge tesseract
- conda install pdf2image
- conda install pytesseract

Comment: For anyone using outside Anaconda, you would need to install tesseract ocr and poppler libraries. Windows users should have these installations' executables' location available in PATH. Then install pytesseract and pdf2image via pip.

Answer (score -1):

PDFBox is a pretty good tool for extracting text from PDF files using Java.  Text extraction is its strength; if you want to modify/annotate or view PDF files, another tool might serve you better.  It has code for identifying spaces in files.

It also has code for handling ligatures, but you need to have a certain internationalization library on the classpath for that to work -- Icu4j.

You could call the PDFBox text extractor from Python as a command-line program, without writing any Java code.

Answer (score -1):

I had solved this issue by using R:

```
library(pdftools)
pdf_file <- "xxx/untitled.pdf"
text <- pdf_text(pdf_file)
cat(text[1])
```