# Python read part of a pdf page

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfminer

I'm trying to read a pdf file where each page is divided into 3x3 blocks of information of the form

```
A | B | C
D | E | F
G | H | I
```

Each of the entries is broken into multiple lines. A simplified example of one entry is [this card](http://spookyshobbyshop.com/TEMPLATE%20si%20sp%20baseball%20card%201979%20EX.JPG). But then there would be similar entries in the other 8 slots.

I've looked at pdfminer and pypdf2. I haven't found pdfminer overly useful, but pypdf2 has given me something close.

```
import PyPDF2
from StringIO import StringIO
def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    p = file(path, "rb")
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(p)
    numPages = pdf.getNumPages()
    for i in range(numPages):
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    content = " ".join(content.replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content
```

However, this only reads the file line by line. I'd like a solution where I can read only a portion of the page so that I could read A, then B, then C, and so on. Also, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737806/extract-text-using-pdfminer-and-pypdf2-merges-columns) works fairly well, but the order of
columns routinely gets distorted and I've only gotten it to read line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the PDF files in question are generated PDFs rather than scanned (as in the example you gave), given that you're using `pdfminer` and `pypdf2`. If you know the size of the columns and rows in inches you can use [`minecart`](https://github.com/felipeochoa/minecart) (full disclosure: I wrote `minecart`). Example code:

```py
import minecart

# minecart units are 1/72 inch, measured from bottom-left of the page
ROW_BORDERS = (
    72 * 1,  # Bottom row starts 1 inch from the bottom of the page
    72 * 3,  # Second row starts 3 inches from the bottom of the page
    72 * 5,  # Third row starts 5 inches from the bottom of the page
    72 * 7,  # Third row ends 7 inches from the bottom of the page
)
COLUMN_BORDERS = (
    72 * 8,  # Third col ends 8 inches from the left of the page
    72 * 6,  # Third col starts 6 inches from the left of the page
    72 * 4,  # Second col starts 4 inches from the left of the page   
    72 * 2,  # First col starts 2 inches from the left of the page
)  # reversed so that BOXES is ordered properly
BOXES = [
    (left, bot, right, top)
    for top, bot in zip(ROW_BORDERS, ROW_BORDERS[1:])
    for left, right in zip(COLUMN_BORDERS, COLUMN_BORDERS[1:])
]

def extract_output(page):
    """
    Reads the text from page and splits it into the 9 cells.

    Returns a list with 9 entries: 

        [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]

    Each item in the tuple contains a string with all of the
    text found in the cell.

    """
    res = []
    for box in BOXES:
        strings = list(page.letterings.iter_in_bbox(box))
        # We sort from top-to-bottom and then from left-to-right, based
        # on the strings' top left corner
        strings.sort(key=lambda x: (-x.bbox[3], x.bbox[0]))
        res.append(" ".join(strings).replace(u"\xa0", " ").strip())
    return res

content = []
doc = minecart.Document(open("path/to/pdf-doc.pdf", 'rb'))
for page in doc.iter_pages():
    content.append(extract_output(page))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd hacked together a solution that did what I needed it to, but maybe minecart is more useful.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? Trying it out on a pdf on my own, and that reference system makes no sence as far as i can tell.