# Why does pdftotext squash words together sometimes?

Tags: python, pdf, file-conversion, pdftotext

I am trying to convert some pdfs into text using pdftotext and the conversion is happening but some words are getting squashed together. For example, `the 2nd day` becomes `the2nd day`, `before me` becomes `beforeme` and so on. Why does this happen and how should I get rid of these discrepancies?

I have tried using okular(since I use linux) to convert pdf to text but that also gives me the same kind of output. And this is bothering because it hinders text extraction a lot.

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/11087993/5320906

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks for pointing me there. I now understand that a space on a pdf can be non printable, when they dont get selected on a pdf reader. But what would be the solution to finding these places and putting spaces so that the word squashing doesn't happen.