# Extract text per page with Python pdfMiner?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I have experimented with both pypdf and pdfMiner to extract text from PDF files. I have some unfriendly PDFs that only pdfMiner is able to extract successfully. I am using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725278/python-help-using-pdfminer-as-a-library) to extract text for the entire file. However, I would really like to extract text on a per page basis like the `pages[i].extract_text()` functionality in pypdf. Does anyone know how to extract text per page using pdfMiner?

Comment: pypdf improved a lot. You might want to give it another try

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for pageNumber, page in enumerate(PDFDocument.get_pages()):
    if pageNumber == 42:
        #do something with the page
```

There is a pretty good article [here](http://denis.papathanasiou.org/?tag=pdfminer).

Comment: Could somebody elaborate on this? I'm having significant trouble getting my head around pdfminer as there is no documentation at all.

Comment: for which version of `pdfminer` does this code work?

Comment: This would appear to broken with the current *pdfminer* (the time of writing of writing 20140328).

Comment: E       AttributeError: type object 'PDFDocument' has no attribute 'get_pages'

Comment: @JoeyBaruch It looks like that method was removed since this answer was written. There is an example here on how to use pdfminer.six that should work instead of this answer. https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/composable.html

Answer (score 11):

This is how you write all the pages to separate files:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import XMLConverter, HTMLConverter, TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
import io
import os

fp = open('Files/Company_list/0010/pdf_files/testfile3.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
retstr = io.StringIO()
print(type(retstr))
codec = 'utf-8'
laparams = LAParams()
device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

page_no = 0
for pageNumber, page in enumerate(PDFPage.get_pages(fp)):
    if pageNumber == page_no:
        interpreter.process_page(page)

        data = retstr.getvalue()

        with open(os.path.join('Files/Company_list/0010/text_parsed/2017AR', f'pdf page {page_no}.txt'), 'wb') as file:
            file.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
        data = ''
        retstr.truncate(0)
        retstr.seek(0)

    page_no += 1
```

Just replace page_no with page number you want if you want specific page numbers.

Comment: It should be io.BytesIO() instead of io.StringIO() for uni-code characters. Everything else works great. :)