# PDFMiner - Get text lines

Tags: python, pdfminer, pdftotext

I'm converting PDF files to text with the [PDFMiner Python library](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/), using the code snippet provided in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8325135/978515). The problem is that the PDF is three column formatted, and I need to read each line. However, the text I get is unordered: sometimes mixes the first and second column, sometimes mixes the third one... As the text does not follow any logical order, I can't parse each line. So, is there any way to get each individual line of the PDF file using PDFMiner?

EDIT:

PDFMiner comes with a command line tool, [`pdf2txt.py`](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/#pdf2txt), to convert PDF to text. Playing with it and setting `0.05` as word margin, I could get a better formatted text, but could not achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar when parsing tables*. What worked for me was to exctract HTML. Then you can parse the HTML table and take the table tags into account (see python documentation for the HTMLParser.) I only had tables to find, tho.

My two cents :)

*Tables from word copied into QT TextEdit widget. Widget accepts rich text, but the tables would be mucked up if exported as text. Exported as HTML, parsed HTML, got data :) Did this at work, don't have the code here.

Comment: can you please add  a link where to find the documentation for the HTMLParser. thanks!

Comment: do you not mean pdfminer.converter.HTMLConverter? the link being https://programtalk.com/python-examples/pdfminer.converter.HTMLConverter/

Answer (score 0):

While working on a similar problem, I stumbled over a somewhat solution for this problem. You can set the LAParams of the extract_text as follows:

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

laparams = LAParams(boxes_flow=None)
```

and then pass it through where extract_text is used:

```
text = extract_text(filename, laparams= laparams)
```

This way, I am getting text that's way more representative of the horizontal and vertical layout of the actual PDF Page.

Comment: what is extract_text here?

Comment: @m9m9m it's a function from pdfminer. You can import it by using
`from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages` assuming you have installed pdfminer