# Python3 error: initial_value must be str or None, with StringIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib2, stringio

While porting code from `python2` to `3`, I get this error when reading from a URL

> TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes.

```
import urllib
import json
import gzip
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request


service_url = 'https://babelfy.io/v1/disambiguate'
text = 'BabelNet is both a multilingual encyclopedic dictionary and a semantic network'
lang = 'EN'
Key  = 'KEY'

    params = {
        'text' : text,
        'key'  : Key,
        'lang' :'EN'

        }

url = service_url + '?' + urllib.urlencode(params)
request = Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
if response.info().get('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip':
            buf = StringIO(response.read())
            f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
            data = json.loads(f.read())
```

The exception is thrown at this line

```
buf = StringIO(response.read())
```

If I use python2, it works fine.

Comment: Can you please provide full traceback?

Comment: It just gives this error and halts.                                                                                
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: can you include the value of your variable `url`? when I try it with `url = 'http://www.google.com'` the code runs fine for me

Comment: To anyone coming here due to `pandas.read_csv()` hiccuping on inferring the wrong encoding on ASCII input, use `encoding='utf8'` or `'latin1'` to force it.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

`response.read()` returns an instance of `bytes` while [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is an in-memory stream for text only. Use [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) instead.

From [What's new in Python 3.0 - Text Vs. Data Instead Of Unicode Vs. 8-bit](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

> The `StringIO` and `cStringIO` modules are gone. Instead, import the `io` module and use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` for text and data respectively.

Answer (score 29):

This looks like another python3 `bytes` vs. `str` problem. Your response is of type `bytes` (which is different in python 3 from `str`). You need to get it into a string first using `response.read().decode('utf-8')` say and then use `StringIO` on it. Or you may want to use `BytesIO` as someone said - but if you expect it to be `str`, preferred way is to `decode` into an `str` first.

Comment: i think this is best answer for modules that can only read from StringIO and BytesIO such as `Bio.SeqIO` as in `records = SeqIO.parse(StringIO(r.read().decode('utf-8')), "fasta")`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using six.StringIO instead of io.StringIO.

Answer (score 0):

And if you are migrating code from python2 to python3 and using suds old version use "suds-py3" for python3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29913868)