# Creating similar behaviour without a 403? (Python Wget)

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

So i have some code that downloads an image, overlays it and shows the result. However I am getting a 403 (probably from user agent) when trying to download from a specific site. How can I create code similar to this that does the same thing?

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import wget
import requests


url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/247096918923149313/34a66572b9339acdaa1dedbcb63bc90a.png?size=256"
filename = wget.download(url)

pp = Image.open(filename)
pp.save("image2c.png")
pp = Image.open("image2c.png").convert("LA")
pp.save("image2c.png")

background = Image.open("image1.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = Image.open("image2c.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = foreground.resize((256, 256), Image.BILINEAR)

background.paste(foreground, (125, 325), foreground)
background.show()
os.remove(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that wget python library have some problems with either https or parameters... You can use requests (you have already imported it).

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO

url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/247096918923149313/34a66572b9339acdaa1dedbcb63bc90a.png?size=256"
response = requests.get(url)
pp = Image.open(StringIO(response.content))
pp.save("image1.png")

pp = Image.open("image2c.png").convert("LA")
pp.save("image2c.png")

background = Image.open("image1.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = Image.open("image2c.png").convert("RGBA")
foreground = foreground.resize((256, 256), Image.BILINEAR)
background.paste(foreground, (125, 325), foreground)
background.show()
```

SEE: [How do I read image data from a URL in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python)

For Python3:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import requests
from io import BytesIO

url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/247096918923149313/34a66572b9339acdaa1dedbcb63bc90a.png?size=256"
response = requests.get(url)
pp = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
pp.save("image1.png")
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31067445/8221879

Comment: I get an error here (using python 3)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Comment: Hmmm, tested on python2.7. Could you try this sugestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31067445/8221879 ?

    from PIL import Image
    import os, sys
    import requests
    from io import BytesIO
    
    url = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/247096918923149313/34a66572b9339acdaa1dedbcb63bc90a.png?size=256"
    response = requests.get(url)
    pp = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    pp.save("image1.png")