# How can I import a google sheet using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have seen the same question and I have tried different the code lines shared but I do not see the same results.

I ran these code lines, but I received the following error messages;

[image]

can you please help me out step by step how can I read a google sheet using pandas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 error: initial\_value must be str or None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064981/python3-error-initial-value-must-be-str-or-none)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use io.BytesIO instead of StringIO.