# PDF text extract with Python3.4

Tags: pdf, python-3.x, pdf-parsing, pdfminer

The texts in the pdf files are text formats, not scanned. PDFMiner does not support python3, is there any other solutions?

Comment: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2 ?

Comment: There is a 3k version of the PDFMiner library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k

Answer (score 3):

There is also the pdfminer2 fork, supported for python 3.4, which available through pip3.
https://github.com/metachris/pdfminer

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725278/how-do-i-use-pdfminer-as-a-library/24273815#24273815) helped me patch something together.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

def readPDF(pdfFile):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)

    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(pdfFile, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    device.close()
    textstr = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return textstr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #scrape = open("../warandpeace/chapter1.pdf", 'rb') # for local files
    scrape = urlopen("http://pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace/chapter1.pdf") # for external files
    pdfFile = BytesIO(scrape.read())
    outputString = readPDF(pdfFile)
    print(outputString)
    pdfFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

For python3, you can download pdfminer as:

`python -m pip install pdfminer.six`

Answer (score 0):

`tika` worked the best for me. It won't be wrong if I say it's better than `PyPDF2` and `pdfminer` This made it really easy to extract each line in the pdf into a list. You can install it by `pip install tika`
And, use the code below:

```
from tika import parser
rawText = parser.from_file(path_to_pdf)
rawList = rawText['content'].splitlines()
print(rawList)
```