# Can't get text out of PDF file with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to get the text from a PDF file I downloaded with PyPDF.
Here is my code:

```
if not PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('download.pdf').isEncrypted:
    PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('download.pdf').getPage(0).extractText()
```

This is the output:

`'\n\n˘ˇ˘ˆ˙\n˝˛˚˜!\n\n\n\n#\nˇ˘ˆ˙ˆ˝˛˝\n˙˙˘ ˘ˆ"˝\n$!%˙(˝)˙*˜+,˝-.#/.(#0)0)/.1.+02345.\n˛˛ˇ/#.$/0/70/#.+322.32˙˘˛˘˘\n˛˘ 8˙˘9:˘ˆ;\n˛˘\n\n˝=\n˙˘˛\n.ˇ<9:˘ˇˇ%˘˛ˇ ˘˘<˘\n˝>"?˝˘$@<˘*ˆˆ˘˙˘A˘B˘˙˘˛ˇ!˛˘˙˘˛ˇ˘\n1C˙ˆ˘06˛˘8+˛9:˘D10+E˝ˆ˘8\n$˘˘9:˘˘1C˙ˆ˘+˘F˛˘D$1+FE˝˘˛˘˘<˘?˝\n////)*˘1˘˛ ?GG˜*HI\nD˘˙A˘E\nJ$\n˛\nDLE///M˛˝˛˙˘˛˘˛\n˛˘˛>"?\n˙˘˛\n˛\n/)M6;˝˛˙˘˛˘\n˛\n///˛\n\n'`

When I open the file its content is fine. Also when I use another program to transform pdf into txt it works fine. It is a javascript rendered pdf on a webpage, don't know if it makes any difference.

Comment: Hi, is the pdf a generated one or is it a scan of a printed page for example?

Comment: its generated by a javascript command

Answer (score 2):

Under Win 7, Python 3.6, I had the problem that PyPDF2 did not properly encode some PDF files. My solution was to use pdfminer.six.

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

To extract text from a PDF, you can use functions such as the one in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42154976/9524424

Worked perfect for me...

Comment: This was helpful. Not sure why this question got downvoted, seems like a real problem and a real solution.

Comment: That was helpful for me as well. Pity that the question was not marked as answered. There are a plenty of similar questions to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from the documentation (https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html)

> extractText() Locate all text drawing commands, in the order they are
>   provided in the content stream, and extract the text. This works well
>   for some PDF files, but poorly for others, depending on the generator
>   used. This will be refined in the future. Do not rely on the order of
>   text coming out of this function, as it will change if this function
>   is made more sophisticated. Returns:  a unicode string object.

So, it seems that the performance of this function depends on the pdf itself.

Comment: I don't think the question is about performance in that sense—it sounds to me like it's about not understand why the text of the PDF file isn't being returned properly from the `extractText()` method.