# Trouble using pdfminer

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am using `python 3.6` on `Mac OS X`. I am using the solution posted [here](http://#%20From%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725278/how-do-i-use-pdfminer-as-a-library/8325135) for using `pdfminer` as a library. I am able to use it as such on `Windows 10`, but not on my Mac. I get the following error:

```
from pdf_to_txt import convert_pdf_to_txt
>>Error: cannot import name 'maxint'
```

Even after going into the `pdfminer` files and changing it to `maxsize`, I get a host of other errors. After some searching, this appears to be an issue with `python 3` compatibility, and the solution is to use `pdfminer.six`. However, after installing, I get the same error; checking `pdfminer.__version__` gives me `20140328` whereas `pdfminer.six`'s most recent version is `20181108`.

How do I make sure I'm using the correct installed version of pdfminer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pdfminer.**version** still answer to your first installation.
I would uninstall it before installing pdfminer.six, as you probably have both at the same time (it's even surprising you could install pdfminer on python 3, as it is not supported in the first place).