# Creating .txt files from pdf files

Tags: python, pdf

Right now I'm writing a program in python that requires you to open a certain .pdf file, control+A (to select all), control C and control V (to copy and paste) on a .txt file, and then run the program.

I was wondering if there's any way I can skip a step and run the program without having to do this sequence of steps, with just a reference to the pdf file inside the program.

Something like:

```
##does the procedure above and saves it on a notes.txt file##
FILE_NAME = 'notes.pdf'
read_pdf(FILE_NAME,'notes.txt')
```

Comment: Try the code here maybe: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511465-pure-python-pdf-to-text-converter/

Comment: There are certain utilities such as `pdftotext`.  You might want to explorer those.

Comment: +1 for `pdftotext`. It's very convenient. You're likely going to have to do some preprocessing on the text, though (in particular if the text contains non-ascii characters).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text

Answer (score 3):

Use [slate](https://github.com/timClicks/slate) module, it depends on the [pdfminer](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer).

To install it:

```
pip install pdfminer==20131113
pip install https://codeload.github.com/timClicks/slate/zip/master
```

To use it:

```
import slate

with open('example.pdf') as fp:
    doc = slate.PDF(fp)

print(len(doc))
print(doc[0])

4
This is a test.
```

Notes:

- The `pdfminer` module don't [support](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html#install) `Python 3`.
- You need to install `slate` from master repo, because [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate/0.3) version of slate is old, and is not [compatible](https://github.com/timClicks/slate/commit/6d2e9e4eac6f0921551d9567ee37d638535a525c) with [last](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/commit/2221163b944d2fd28b9a46a6b73d049a533d009e) [change](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/commit/d3730a29ecf238f6ca2c8f72c53755db69b75654) of `pdfminer`.

Or use [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2) :

To install it:

```
pip install PyPDF2
```

To use it:

```
import PyPDF2

pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('sample.pdf', "rb"))

print(pdf.getNumPages())
print(pdf.getPage(0).extractText())

1
This is a sample.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways and many utilities you can use to do that step automatically.

There is a module for Python on Windows that does GUI automation: [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/), but it's Windows only.

You can use a pure python library like [PyPDF2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/) which has an `extractText` function. Or [PDFMiner](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html).

The [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) library has also its python bindings and can be used to extract text pretty much like PyPDF2.

You can call external programs from python like [pdftotext](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) from Xpdf.