# Convert all pdf in a folder to text files and store them in different folders using python

Tags: python

Im trying to convert all the pdf stored in one file, say 60 pdfs into text documents and store them in different folders. the folder should have unique names.
i tried this code.The folders where created, but the pdftotext conversion command doesnt work in the loop:

```
import os
def listfiles(path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
                print(f)
        newpath = r'/home/user/files/'
        p=f.replace("pdf","")
        newpath=newpath+p 
        if not os.path.exists(newpath): os.makedirs(newpath)
        os.system("pdftotext f f.txt")

f=listfiles("/home/user/reports")
```

Comment: do you just want to create a text version of each pdf in the same directory as the original, or create the text version in a folder somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

One problem here is the `os.system("pdftotext f f.txt")` call. I assume you want the f's here replaced with the current file in the loop. If that is the case you need to change this to `os.system("pdftotext {0} {0}.txt".format(f))`

Another issue may be that the working directory is not being set up so the call to system is looking for the file in the wrong place. Try using [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) every time you change folders.

to place the text file in a diffrent folder try:

```
os.system("pdftotext {0} {1}/{0}.txt".format(f, newpath))
```

Comment: it worked.. but not placed in different folders! anyway thanks

Comment: @Aliya, no problem. I added an edit to show how to place the the text file in newpath/f.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but I think I can clearly see a mistake there. It looks like you are just replacing the ".pdf" with a ".txt". Since a PDF isn't just plain text, this won't work.
For the convertion look at the top answer of this post:
[Python module for converting PDF to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text)

Comment: no, @Aliya is using a pdftotext tool called from the command line

Comment: i was trying to create a folder for abc.pdf named abc.

Comment: i want to call the terminal command pdftotext... eg:pdftotext abc.pdf ff.txt, creates a text file ff.txt for the file abc.pdf.. i want this to happen for all the pdf in my file.. i want it to wrok in  loop

Comment: In the command line where you call pdftotext, are you currently in the directory where you want to put that textfile in? Does it help if you give pdftptext a path as a parameter like "path/to/ff.text"?
How do you know, that the conversion doesn't work? Are they just not listed? Maybe you converted them, but they are located somewhere else, now.