# Is there a python module that reads a pdf and converts it to text

Tags: python, pdf, module

I mean one that is a scanned image or something like that and converts it to text or is there a way to do it

Edit: Btw this isnt meant to be a duplicate i wanna know if i can get text out of a scanned image not a regular PDF

Comment: searched for "python character recognition" https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract

Comment: quote http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper for Tesseract OCR is available https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserocr

Answer (score 0):

Try PDFminer, it might suit what you need.

http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html