# IBM Watson, how to input data of entire books

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

Im using the IBM Watson analytics trial, it says it only takes data as CSV, Excel and a few others. How can i convert books or bodies of text into an acceptable format? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the architecture of WCA(Watson Context Analytics) does not support PDF itself. Please refer the following images from IBM [Link](https://www.slideshare.net/perficientinc/ibm-watson-content-analytics-discover-hidden-value-in-your-unstructured-data)

[image]

I think it would be better to convert pdf to text with converter such as [CONVERTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text) and pushing it into database or others.
Then, you can crawing the text data from it.

FYI, the document has to have a KEY column (i.e. name of the book).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do convert your book into an acceptable text format *(.csv. .xls, .xlsx. .sav)*, Watson Analytics isn't optimized for text analytics. It sounds like [Watson Explorer](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/content-analytics) is the offering that'd best suit your needs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even though CSV or XLS is the acceptable format of the file, Datasets needs to be in the specific structure. You need headers for all the tables and data following it. I am not sure how a data of the book can fit into that format.

I have recently published this blog post on [how to structure and refine data before importing into Watson Analytics](http://digitalconqurer.com/dev-corner/import-refine-data-watson-analytics/) to get the best results.

For your specific requirement, you can look into Watson Explorer as suggested by Brennan above, or even better you can learn to use [IBM Content Analytics here.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS5RWK_3.5.0/com.ibm.discovery.es.nav.doc/contentanalytics_350.htm)