# How can I convert pdf to asciidoc using pandoc?

Tags: pdf, pandoc, asciidoc

I am trying to convert pdf book to asciidoc document.I have tried the following command:

```
pandoc -s s.pdf -t asciidoc -o example28.txt
```

I got "Unknown reader" problem.

> ```
> q@q-ABRA-A5-V12-1:~/Downloads$ pandoc -s s.pdf -t asciidoc -o example28.txt
> pandoc: Unknown reader: pdf
> Pandoc can convert to PDF, but not from PDF.
> ```

How can I fix this or is there another way to convert from pdf to asciidoc?

Comment: pandoc doesn't read pdfs, only produces them. but you could try `less s.pdf | pandoc -t asciidoc`

Comment: When I try this command I get "pandoc: Unknown reader: plain" error.

Comment: ah right, you leave the `-f`, it will default to markdown... but probably you want a dedicated tool anyway. but stackoverflow is probably the wrong place to ask for that. also depends on your plattform / needs.

Comment: See also this more generic question: [Python module for converting PDF to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665/python-module-for-converting-pdf-to-text) which has many more answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried pdf2txt? 
https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/
It's one of the tools provided there.

Comment: seems to go to HTML, and then you can use pandoc to go from HTML to asciidoc: `pdf2txt.py -t html input.pdf | pandoc -f html -t asciidoc`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have converted pdf to asciidoc but I have extra newline problem which is probably caused extra <br> blocks on html.How can I fix this problem? From : https://i.imgur.com/QJ3Mx0n.png To:https://i.imgur.com/XoURhd9.png

Comment: As of 2020, PDFMiner is not actively maintained. This is the community maintained fork: [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six).