# How can read data from pdf file using cakephp

Tags: pdf, cakephp-2.1

I need to read data from a pdf file using cakephp.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, I found this [Cakephp-pdfview-plugin](https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-pdfview-plugin) doing a quick google.

Also see this question: [What's the best way to import/read data from pdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550/whats-the-best-way-to-import-read-data-from-pdf-files)

Good luck!

*ps telling everyone its urgent is likely to cause the opposite affect that you want*

Comment: ThankQ Jeremy Thompson i got it and also i need one more information that how to read data from xps file can you please tell me yar its urgent