# Import PDF Fields into Database

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, pdf, extract

I'm trying to import fields from a fill-able PDF into a sql databse.
I can't seem to find an answer online:
[What's the best way to import/read data from pdf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550/whats-the-best-way-to-import-read-data-from-pdf-files)
[Insert a PDF file into Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788414/insert-a-pdf-file-into-core-data)'
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Import-Fillable-Pfd-Data-t1971535.html

So I'm wondering does anyone know how to extract data from a fill-able PDF into a database(or excel from which it can be imported into a database)

Thanks

Comment: If you say "import fields from a fillable PDF", do you mean that you want to extract the field values of an existing PDF (so after filling and saving), or do you mean capture the form data after a user manually fills the form?

Comment: I mean extracting field values from a saved form.

Answer (score 0):

Data from fillable pdf's can be exported into an .FDF file, which is a text file.  [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is a command-line utility that will allow you to extract the data programmatically.  You will then need to write a custom parser to pull the data out of the .FDF file.

It won't be a lot of fun, but it should be do-able.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdftk. I used it and it's great works like a charm. Lot's of coding though. You can get back at me if you need any help